# Virtual Host Error in Ubuntu 12

Tags: perl, ubuntu, virtualhost

When I am trying to create virtual host on my Ubuntu using this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) 
I am getting following error while entering following command. -

```
 sudo a2ensite localhostmagentoce2.com
```

Error -

```
Feature bundle "5.16" is not supported by Perl 5.14.2 at /usr/sbin/a2ensite line 14
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/sbin/a2ensite line 14.
```

As I used this tutorial so many time but never get any error.

I checked about this error but didn't find any useful info.

I have downloaded latest Perl Version 5.22.1

But dont know how to install tar.gz file

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: `use feature ":5.16";` does not work under `perl <5.16` and what you have is `5.14.2`

Comment: I tried to update Perl also. Still not working

Comment: Output of `perl -v` should be 5.16 or higher.

Comment: No its 5.14.2 version. How to update it

Answer (score 1):

In order to install a new version of Perl, while still keeping the existing one, I'll recommend using PerlBrew:

http://blog.endpoint.com/2011/02/managing-perl-environments-with.html

We have been using it in our work environment since many years and it works very well.

Homepage: http://perlbrew.pl/

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, Done!